# Disputed review - CSS change value of default base color keywords

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

Please look at the following question for which I recently failed an audit review:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/14559819

> I'm wondering if it is possible to change the color values for the CSS base color keywords?...

It seems to me to be a duplicate of the following question, answered two years earlier and with more votes:

[Can the default named CSS colors be overidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21036884/can-the-default-named-css-colors-be-overidden)

> ...I was wondering if there is way to override the default named color definition as defined in the HTML/CSS specification with these new colors.

Hence, I flagged it as a duplicate and failed the audit. I would argue in this context 'change' is equivalent to 'override' and the answers are also the similar. However, I am prepared to accept a reasoned argument as to why it is not a duplicate. My concern is not that I personally failed the audit but that, since the audit questions are selected by an algorithm, it is possible for mistaken audit questions to emerge.

Comment: (FWIW, I would say that the audit, rather than you, is mistaken, just like in the other Meta question.)

Comment: @duplode should we still raise a question here on meta to mark the individual question and possibly have it removed from future review audits?

Comment: The close vote that I have just cast [should do the trick](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/197484/242059).